# Formula to check if content of the cell is matching a format, regex?

Tags: excel, regex, excel-formula

I have to check if the content of a cell matchs with a specific format.

If it is the case, then I have to put `Yes` else `No` in the `Result` column.

Format is the following one : `REFXXXX(,REFXXXX,...)`.

Content into bracket is optional and `X` should be a sequence of number (minimum 8, maximum 12).

**Data example**

```
Reference                              | Result
REF12324567                            | Yes
REF1                                   | No
                                       | No
Some text                              | No
REF1234567,REF789654123,REF741258963   | Yes
```

With a regex, it can be `REF(\d{8,12})((,REF(\d{8,12}))*)`

However I don't know if it is possible to use a regex as Excel formula.

Can you please explain me how to do?

Thank you, Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct equivalent being a worksheetfunction. You could however use `FILTERXML()` as some sort of replacement feature to "split" a string into different elements and use some xpath to validate each element.

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=IF(AND(ISERROR(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[not(starts-with(., 'REF') and string-length() >=11 and string-length() <=15 and translate(., 'REF', '')*0=0)]")),A1<>""),"Yes","No")
```

- `"<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>"` - Create a valid xml-string.
- `//s` - Return s-nodes where:

  - `not(starts-with(., 'REF')` - s-nodes do **not** start with "REF", and;
  - `string-length() >=11 and string-length() <=15` - A string is of a total lenght between 11-15, and;
  - `translate(., 'REF', '')*0=0` - If "REF" is removed the remainder is numeric.

If there is no s-nodes that can be returned after this validation `FILTERXML()` will throw an error which we catch with `ISERROR()` nested inside an `IF()` to return "Yes" or "No".

- Note that `FILTERXML()` is case-sensitive.
- Note that your 4th sample does not validate.
- Note that you could also look at building your own **UDF** (User Defined Function) through the use of VBA and the regex-object. This way you can use regular expressions as you know it. For information on that subject, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22542834/9758194) great source.

If you wish to know more about the use of `FILTERXML()` I'd like to redirect you to: [Excel - Extract substring(s) from string using FILTERXML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61837696/9758194)